# Show chart js in website with php and search box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I had a search box on other web page and I'm just trying to use it in order to filter the data shown in a chart in another one.
The search box is working and passing the variable to php to retrieve the data in a json. I think the problem is when the javascript is trying to get this json.

I have attached some code to explain it.

```
<?php $result = $connection->query($query);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
$result->close();
$connection->close();
print json_encode($data);
echo "Nombre jugador:"."$licencia_select"."$searchkey";
}
?>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url : "http://statennis.es/search/new_index.php",
    type : "GET",
    success : function (data){
        console.log(data); (all the code to show the chart)
```

When I used this code I can see the json in the screen but the chart is empty.

Comment: Share the relevant code for a possible solution.. Where is the chart code are you using to create chart?

Answer (score 0):

i assume when you said - (all the code to show the chart) you meant that the info reaches the js appropriately and is shown in the log.

maybe you forgot JSON.parse in the js, or maybe it doesn't work well because you echoed after you printed the json.

Comment: It was just to don't paste all the code, specifiying that in this part of code I wrote all the chart js code in order to show the charts.